# Ember.js controllers 'needs' syntax

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I am using the controller dependency helper `needs` for my ember controller. I know the basic syntax:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: 'post'
```

and then you can access the dependency controller as `controllers.post`

But what if you require a controller that is nested:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: 'users/show'
```

How do you access this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way. You can access every dependent controller by using syntax controllers.*controller_name_from_needs*.*property_name*

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: 'users/show',
    init: function() {
        this._super();

        controller = this.get('controllers.users/show');
        console.log("dependent controller: ", controller);
    }
});
```